# How to partition a unpartitioned hive table created from another table

Tags: hive

I want to use dynamic partitioning to partition a table for which I have created a schema before hand.

The partition key I want to have is a column from the source table.

So, basically I want to achieve is the following

insert overwrite table table_dest

select col1,col2,col3 from table_source

The Partition key that I want to use here is col3.

Also, Can I change the partition column name while running the dynamic partition query?

Also, any things to take into consideration while running a query that runs dynamic partitioning, as it generates a lot many intermediate files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this would work,
dynamic.partition.mode should be set to nonstrict mode only if there are no static partitions at a higher level to the dynamic partition.

Here the paritioning column should be the last column in the select list. Hence the select list would n+1 columns and target table would have n columns.

```
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition = true;

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE table_dest
partition(col3)
Select
col1
,col2
,col3
from  source;
```